# Detecting multitouch iPhone-like "tap" on MacBookPro

Tags: cocoa, macos, multi-touch

After a period of iPhone work, I'm once again working on normal Cocoa apps on my MBP
and I miss the "tap" gesture. I know that I can turn on the incredibly annoying "Tap to Click",
feature in the Trackpad control pannel, but I don't want a click, I want a tap.

I know it's probably not mac canon, but is it possible to receive this multi-touch style event?

Comment: Wait for Snow Leopard.  Given the NDA, that's all I'll say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the native code underpinning my Java API: http://kenai.com/projects/macmultitouch

Comment: Thank you, the private 10.5 MultiTouchSupport framework, while strange, does exactly what I want.

Comment: P.S. This API allows you to finally give a "sorry, your fingers are too fat" error.